# How many webgl.draw calls does Three.js make for a given number of geometries/materials/meshes

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

How would I calculate the number of drawArrays/drawElements calls THREE.renderer.render(scene, camera) would make?

I'm assuming one call per geometry, with attributes for the materials/mesh properties. But that could easily be wrong or incomplete.

Also, would using the BufferGeometry etc make a difference?

Comment: Type `renderer.info` into the console and you can do some experiments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

rstats is what i am using, it's pretty cool,
you can get almost all important information:
framerate, memory, render info, webgl drawcall...

it really helps in threejs performance.

a great work from [Jaume Sanchez](http://www.clicktorelease.com)

here is tutorial:
https://spite.github.io/rstats/

Answer (score 2):

Per WestLangley's comment, i'd search the `THREE.WebglRenderer` for [renderer.info](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderer.info) and look at [the logic](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/cce7e3170ed6127123c12fb8d05a2eec03a0d78d/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLInfo.js) there.

The drawcalls themselves differ a bit. If you have one geometry, lets say `cubeGeometry`, one material `cubeMaterialRed`, and five cube nodes `[c1,c2...,c5]`, youll have five draw calls. I believe three.js would then bind the geometry once, and do five consecutive draw calls, with the same shader, and mostly the same uniforms (only the position/rotation/scale matrix should change, while the color red could be bound once).

If you have five different materials `[cMatRed, cMatBlue... cMatPink]`, youll have five draw calls with the same geometry, but the uniform for the color of the material will be set differently for each one.

If you have five different geometries, in five different nodes, the geometry will have to be bound before every draw call.

This can be reduced by using instancing when supported. In the second example, it would bound the geometry to be instanced once, and set up attributes containing the position/rotation/scale and colors, one draw call would be issued with these properties, rendering 5 geometries, in the locations and color provided by the attribute.

Three.js currently does not do any batching and optimization along those lines so instancing would be done manually.

This all means that it's pretty much 1:1 relation to the number of nodes that contain geometry. `Object3D->Object3D->Mesh` would result in three nodes, but one draw call.